# Merging dictionaries function with for/in statement

Tags: python, dictionary, merge

I'm a beginner in Python so I'm in need of a simple explanations.

I have two dictionaries:

```py
supply_dictionarie = {'Apple': 20, 'Cigar': 100, 'Milk': 210, 'Flower': 75}

goods_dictionarie = {'Milk': 210, 'Apple': 50, 'WhiteWine': 200, 'Beer': 300, 'Oranges': 400}
```

I'm trying to merge those two dictionaries while summing the values for repeated keys. My intention is to obtain:

```
merged_dictionarie = {'Milk': 420, 'Cigar': 100, 'Apple': 70, 'WhiteWine': 200, 'Beer': 300, 'Oranges': 400, 'Flower': 75} *(not necessarily in this order)
```

I'm using the following code:

```py
def merge_supply():
    for k in supply_dictionarie:
        if k in set(goods_dictionarie):
            merged_dictionarie[k] = goods_dictionarie.get(k, 0) + supply_dictionarie.get(k, 0)
        elif k not in set(goods_dictionarie):
            merged_dictionarie[k] = supply_dictionarie.get(k, 0)
        else:
            break
    for k in goods_dictionarie:
         if k not in set(supply_dictionarie):
            merged_dictionarie[k] = goods_dictionarie.get(k, 0)
         else:
            break
```

But all I obtain is:

`merged_dictionarie = {'Apple': 70, 'Cigar': 100, 'Milk': 420, 'Flower': 75}`

This, to me, indicates that the second "for/in" expression is not performing the job successfully. What is going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You may simplify your loops using this:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> merged = defaultdict(int)
>>> for i in supply_dictionarie :
...     merged[i] += supply_dictionarie[i]
... 
>>> for i in goods_dictionarie :
...     merged[i] += goods_dictionarie[i]
... 
>>> dict(merged)
{'Beer': 300, 'Flower': 75, 'Apple': 70, 'Cigar': 100, 'WhiteWine': 200, 'Oranges': 400, 'Milk': 420}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
> $ ipython3                                                                                                                 
Python 3.8.2 (default, Apr  8 2020, 14:31:25) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.14.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: from collections import Counter                                                                                       

In [2]: supply_dictionarie = Counter({'Apple': 20, 'Cigar': 100, 'Milk': 210, 'Flower': 75})                                  

In [3]: goods_dictionarie = Counter({'Milk': 210, 'Apple': 50, 'WhiteWine': 200, 'Beer': 300, 'Oranges': 400})                

In [4]: dict(supply_dictionarie + goods_dictionarie)                                                                          
Out[4]: 
{'Apple': 70,
 'Cigar': 100,
 'Milk': 420,
 'Flower': 75,
 'WhiteWine': 200,
 'Beer': 300,
 'Oranges': 400}
```